# Getting exception 'Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5' after updating Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated my Gradle today and I now get this error:

```
  > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5.
     > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.5/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.5.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.5/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.5.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

Apparently, there's something wrong with the server (`Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway`). What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` on your repositories at `build.gradle` project level.

Will look like this:

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
     maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: in my case I update Maven to :
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }

Comment: @Maher should use the full url: `maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2' }`